# User-profile undefined only in the navbar and pin section of the React sanity app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, react-hooks, sanity

I’m trying to get the user's Google name and profile photo into my React app (with sanity as backend), but it only works in the home and sidebar section of the app, but not in the navbar and pin section.

There aren’t any errors in the console other than:

> react-dom.development.js:86  Warning: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. Use createRoot instead. Until you switch to the new API, your app will behave as if it's running React 17.

I've run out of options. What can I do?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { IoMdAdd, IoMdSearch } from 'react-icons/io';

const Navbar = ({ searchTerm, setSearchTerm, user }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  if (!user) return null;
    return (
      <div className="flex gap-2 md:gap-5 w-full mt-5 pb-7 ">
        <div className="flex justify-start items-center w-full px-2 rounded-md bg-white border-none outline-none focus-within:shadow-sm">
          <IoMdSearch fontSize={21} className="ml-1" />
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={(e) => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="Search"
            value={searchTerm}
            onFocus={() => navigate('/search')}
            className="p-2 w-full bg-white outline-none"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="flex gap-3 ">
          <Link to={`user-profile/${user?._id}`} className="hidden md:block">
            <img src={user.image} alt="user" className="w-14 h-12 rounded-lg " />
          </Link>
          <Link to="/create-pin" className="bg-black text-white rounded-lg w-12 h-12 md:w-14 md:h-12 flex justify-center items-center">
            <IoMdAdd />
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: Generally if you're running code that is compliant with react 17 and below, you wouldn't necessarily have to be worried that you're made aware of this.

I have tried to put more words on it in an answer, basically  it's good. React is committing to the async pattern and whilst it is a bit annoying to program it does increase performance by not blocking main execution context on lengthy thing.

The possible help in this is get familiar with react 18 method and reimplement based on that, I have provided a simplified example. Obviously Your career will not get furthered by a direct solve :)

Comment: But is this what is causing the error?